# Writing new column with <, >, and <= x <=

Tags: pandas

I'm almost finished writing a program that will iterate through a csv file composed of two csv files. I'm stuck on the final column that is suppose to list damage_done > 700000 as 'High, damage_done < as 'Low', and 300000 <= damage_done <= 699999 as 'Medium'. I have tried writing a loop and doing direct assignments, but the follow error is being thrown:     TypeError: ("'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index 0').

1.
    def quality(row):
        if (row['damage_done'] > 700000):
            df3['dps_quality'] = 'High'
        if (row['damage_done'] < 300000):
            df3['dps_quality'] = 'Low'
        if (300000 <= row['damage_done'] <= 699999):
            df3['dps_quality'] = 'Medium'

```
df3['dps_quality'] = df3.apply(quality, axis = 1)
df3
```

and
2.

```
df3['dps_quality'][df3['damage_done'] > 700000] = 'High'
df3['dps_quality'][df3['damage_done'] < 300000] = 'Low'
df3['dps_quality'][300000 <= df3['damage_done'] <= 699000] = 'High'

import pandas as pd
import io
import requests as r

url = 'http://drd.ba.ttu.edu/isqs6339/hw/hw2/'
path = '/Users/jeredwilloughby/Desktop/Business Intelligence/'
file1 = 'players.csv'
file2 = 'player_sessions.csv'
fileout = 'pandashw.csv'

res1 = r.get(url + file1)
res1.status_code
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res1.text), delimiter='|')
df1

res2 = r.get(url + file2)
res2.status_code
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res2.text), delimiter=',')
df2.head(5)
df2.tail(5)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="left", on="playerid")
df3.describe()
list(df3)
df3.count()

df3['damage_done'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df3.count()

df3.to_csv(path + fileout)

def performance(row):
    return (row['damage_done']*2.5 + row['healing_done']*4.5)/4

df3['player_performance_metric'] = df3.apply(performance, axis = 1)
df3
df3.to_csv(path + fileout)

def quality(row):
    if (row['damage_done'] > 700000):
        df3['dps_quality'] = 'High'
    if (row['damage_done'] < 300000):
        df3['dps_quality'] = 'Low'
    if (300000 <= row['damage_done'] <= 699999):
        df3['dps_quality'] = 'Medium'

df3['dps_quality'] = df3.apply(quality, axis = 1)
df3
```

Expected: The cvs file output will have a new column titled 'dps_quality' with associated high, medium, low values.

Actual: TypeError: ("'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index 0').

Comment: You can try `.astype('int')` or `pd.to_numeric` functions .. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

Answer (score 1):

1. The column `damage_done` should have numeric objects (`int` or `float`), not `strings`.
2. The method `.apply` invokes the function `quality` for each row.
   Whichever value he function returns will compose the series the method will return.
   This series, as written in your code, will be assigned to the column `dps_quality` in your dataframe.
   So, there is no need to use the column name inside the function.

Considering these two, a possible fix would be:

```
def quality(damage_done):
    # this line assures that the value will be interpreted as an integer
    damage_done = int(damage_done)
    if damage_done > 700000:
        # now we are returning a value, instead of assigning it directly to the column
        return 'High'
    if damage_done < 300000:
        return 'Low'
    # removing the last check as it is not necessary
    return 'Medium'

# we are using the .apply method only on a series. This makes the reading easier
df3['dps_quality'] = df3['damage_done'].apply(quality)
```